# How to secure your App.config on remote PCs

Tags: c#, wix, rsa

In my app.config, I saved all the important stuff of my application (password, connection strings).
I encrypt this stuff with an RSA key container.

When the setup is installed on a remote PC, the setup also imports the RSA key container (*.xml). Like this, my application is capable to decrypt the file:

`Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);`

The problem is: I'm also capable to decrypt the app.config file with this instruction:

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" "\myAppPath"`

Is it possible to protect the RSA key container to be only accessible by the application?

Do you have another solution for my problem?

FYI: I use Wix as installer and all the remote PCs don't have internet access. So, a web server is not a solution (I think).

Comment: As you have discovered, if your app can decrypt then a user can too. For connection strings, can you not use Integrated Windows Security? The typical way to do this is to have a service layer that contains these secrets. If you can't stand up any kind of service then you can't absolutely protect your data, you can only try to obscure it from mortals.

Comment: Do you have an example of Integrated Windows Security to use in connectionStrings of c# application?

Comment: Yes, but there's more to it than just a connection string. The server must be set up for Active Directory logins and then you have to assign roles/permissions in the database. But at minimum a connection string would look something like: `Data Source=your-server-name;Initial Catalog=the-database-name;Integrated Security=True;`. BTW, I'm assuming Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: You can run another service that just does the rsa encryption (reads the key) and run the service as admin.  Then the key is only accessible to an admin an not other users.

Comment: You mean... I create a service (server) with my installer which contain all the important inforamtion of my application.. and then, each time the application need this infromation, she connect to the server as an admin?  
But, if the service is in the same PC.. it's also crackable no?

Answer (score 0):

You need a trusted third party to establish a connection between new installation A and existing installation B. A needs to fetch a token from B that will allow to decrypt the config. This could be done upon installation. Once the token is received, store and reuse it throughout the application's lifetime.

The trusted third party could be a server (check Kerberos) or the person who is installing the software. Either way both parties A and B have to agree on a secret key to decrypt the config.

If there is no prior installation, then set it up as master that will generate such a key. To encrypt the config you can either use DES or RSA, up to you. It's just a matter of distributing the keys in a secure manner. See also [Key-agreement protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-agreement_protocol).